# Getting the thickness of a contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a program that uses `findContours` function and this is the result  that I get:

[image: result]

My question is: Is there any way to get the thickness of those bars without using the `houghlines` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use cv::reduce method for summing up all nonzero pixels along rows, and the same for cols. You'll get two histograms. The max values will have coords of your lines.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce
you need use it with flag CV_REDUCE_SUM or CV_REDUCE_AVG.